# GHC does not generate a binary despite no errors shown

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

GHC is telling me it worked, yet it doesn't generate a binary. I don't know why

```
$  ls
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 drewgross  staff   361B  9 Sep 01:21 MouseMove.hs
$  ghc MouseMove.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling MouseMove        ( MouseMove.hs, MouseMove.o )
$  echo $?
0
$  ls
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 drewgross  staff   926B  9 Sep 01:29 MouseMove.hi
-rw-r--r--  1 drewgross  staff   361B  9 Sep 01:21 MouseMove.hs
-rw-r--r--  1 drewgross  staff   5.7K  9 Sep 01:29 MouseMove.o
```

Here is my MouseMove.hs file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module MouseMove where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types

import Control.Applicative

foreign import ccall "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CGRemoteOperation.h CGWarpMouseCursorPosition"
    c_warp :: CFloat -> CFloat -> IO CInt

main = print =<< (fromIntegral <$> c_warp 100 100)
```

and my GHC version is

```
$  ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

Any ideas? Without an error message I don't know what to try.

Comment: If I remember correctly you have to link the c file too. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction

Comment: There is no module named Main, so this isn't a program.

Comment: Oops. Completely forgot about that line. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GHC will create a program if there is a module named `Main` and a function named `main` inside it. In your case you have `main`, but not in `Main`.

Either remove the `module MouseMove` header from `MouseMove.hs`, or pass `-main-is MouseMove.main` to GHC.